# How to resolve the Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am updated my android studio 3.2.1 and also gradle version 4.6 . My b buildToolsVersion '28.0.3' but i am getting Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable error in my console even i tried clean build and also remove  volley.jar and also updated compile to implementation but still i am getting this issue

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation('com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    implementation('com.github.florent37:materialviewpager:1.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'
    }
    implementation('com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation project(':linkedin-sdk')
    implementation 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rtoshiro.fullscreenvideoview:fullscreenvideoview:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom:imagezoom:2.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:1.3.15'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.9"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please guide me , even i remove the gar file of volley  its occur some error in internal files .like com.android.volley.AuthFailureError; not exit

Comment: Could you please post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Do you get this error before updating Android Studio and gradle?

Comment: i did't get any error in before update .

Comment: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

Comment: and also  Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
and    Program type already present: com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1`

Comment: i tried     implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
also but still i am getting same issue ..

Comment: Error: Program type already present: com.android.volley.BuildConfig
please help me any one....